# Area inside the cardioid $r=2+2\sin\theta$ and outside the circle $r=1$

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

Simply I saw a friend asking about the area inside the cardoid $r=2+2\sin \theta$ and outside the circle $r=1$ and I couldn't help.
I know that the area is equal to $$
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{2}((2+2\sin \theta)^2-1) \,d\theta
$$
But when I tried to solve the equation $$
2+2\sin \theta =1
$$
I found $\sin \theta =-\frac{1}{2}$
Which means $\theta=-\pi/6$.

Now I'm not quite sure should $a$ be equal to $-\pi/6$ or $7\pi/6$?, and for $b$ should it be $5\pi/6$.

Its so confusing for me because I didn't expect negative sin.

[That's what I got when I tried to plot the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24VqY.jpg)

Comment: Why $b=5\pi/6$? That does not satisfy $2+2\sin b = 1$.

Comment: Whether the $\sin$ is negative should not matter much. If the question asks for the area outside the circles $r=2$ or $r=3$, the steps to determine intersection points are similar.

Comment: @peterwhy Ok that's for the lower bound right? Now what about the upper one how should I calculate it ?

Comment: The intersections of the cardioid and the circle by definition satisfies $2+2\sin\theta = 1$, if you pick the lower bound $a=-\pi/6$ (the purple intersection to the lower-right), then the upper bound would be the next intersection $b=7\pi/6$ (the green intersection to the lower-left).

Comment: @peterwhy okay I think I got everything now but there is only one question how is the lower-right intersection at $-\pi/6$ ? Shouldn't it be $11\pi/6$? Or $-5\pi/6$.

Comment: You may alternatively choose $a=11\pi/6 = 2\pi-\pi/6$, then the next intersection for the upper bound would be $b=19\pi/6 = 3\pi+\pi/6$. But NOT $-5\pi/6$; that intersection is to the lower-left in the 3rd quadrant.

Comment: @peterwhy Okay got it now thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot the graph to guess the values. I think you should integrate from $-\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ to $\dfrac{7\pi}{6}$.

Comment: the numbers appear because they are only values of $\theta$ s.t $\sin(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: When I plotted the graph I found it starting at $\pi/6$ and ending at $7\pi/6$, so why did you pick $-\pi/6$

Comment: @AhmedRamsey Why from $\pi/6$? That does not satisfy $2+2\sin \theta = 1$.

Comment: @peterwhy So I should start from the same theta I got from the equation?

Comment: I bet you mistook somewhere, in drawing the graph or interpreting it. An intersection is certainly on the line $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{6}$. And $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$ cannot be the intersection.

Comment: @riemann18 I added a picture from the graph, can u check it ?

Comment: Yes. I saw the graph and it was correct. So it should start at the point $(r, \theta) = (1, -\frac{\pi}{6})$ which is the rightmost intersection. Why do you think that it starts from $\frac{\pi}{6}$?

Comment: @riemann18 how is the right most intersection $-\pi/6$?, omg I feel so fool now

Comment: Angle is defined by starting from the $x$-axis, rotating counterclockwise. If you rotate $\frac{\pi}{6}$ clockwise, then you will get $-\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @riemann18 got it now thanks for the clarification